# sql query column value = column value - 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to -1 from a column on each row of a table and I was wondering if there was a way to do this with SQL rather than writing something in PHP?

On each row there is a "score" column and I need to -1 from the value on each row.

In php I'd use something like

```
foreach ( $rows as $row ){
     $score = $row->score - 1; 
     $this->update_score($score, $row->id);
}
```

But with 3000+ records to update, there must be a better way?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: SQL `column = column - 1`

Comment: From my understanding below query may help. **Update yourTable set colName = colName -1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET score = score - 1
```

Comment: Well that was easy... thanks a lot! I'll accept this as the answer in 5 minutes when it allows me to :D

Comment: No worries. Glad to have been of help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do it the simple way.

```
UPDATE table SET score = score-1
```